# File Size Validation using typescript at the time of upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to file size validation using typescript at the time of file upload but still not working.
Because typescript not found "size" property

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle

You can get file size and reject it from javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/qger8xte/

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('fileupload').addEventListener('change', checkFile, false);

    function checkFile(e) {

        var file_list = e.target.files;

        for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {
            var sFileName = file.name;
            var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
            var iFileSize = file.size;
            var iConvert = (file.size / 10485760).toFixed(2);

            if (!(sFileExtension === "pdf" || sFileExtension === "doc" || sFileExtension === "docx") || iFileSize > 10485760) {
                txt = "File type : " + sFileExtension + "\n\n";
                txt += "Size: " + iConvert + " MB \n\n";
                txt += "Please make sure your file is in pdf or doc format and less than 10 MB.\n\n";
                alert(txt);
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileupload">
```